# "bound" or "bonded"

Tags: grammar, word-choice, programming

If I use a computer command like:

```
bind keystroke macro
```

I refer to that keystroke as being bound to that macro. Is it also correct to say that they are bonded?

If I bind a bunch of twigs together, they are bound, but I don't think they are bonded.

Can "bound" and "bonded" be used interchangeably? Under what circumstances?

Comment: @joshdick: This question is barely even tangentially related to programming. Is it really necessary to have it tagged `[programming]`?

Comment: I think it's useful to tag posts with subject-specific tags like this, and it certainly doesn't do any harm. I posted in meta asking what people think, and no one objected.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Bound* is the past tense of *bind*, while *bonded* is the past tense of an entirely different word, *bond*. I don't believe I've ever met a situation where the two words could be used interchangeably.

Comment: "bind" and "bond" have similar etymologies in some senses so I would say they were entirely different words.

Comment: @Dennis, are you missing a 'not'? But beware the etymological fallacy: the fact that two words are related, as these clearly are, does not of itself tell you that they are in any way connected in the current language.

Comment: @Colin: Yes, my comment should say "they were *not* entirely different words".

Comment: to bind and to bond have pretty similar meanings though, and often things that are bound are in fact also bonded.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you mean "bounded"? In any case, the answer is no:

- **bound** - past of **to bind**.
- **bonded** - past of **to bond**.
- **bounded** - past of **to bound**.

So in each case it's a different verb.

Comment: I think he probably does mean 'bounded', but good summary anyway.

Comment: @Noldorin: No, I do not mean "bounded". That means either "having a boundary" or "bounced".

Comment: It that case I can't even see a potential source of confusion..!

Answer (score 4):

In programming, we say that the keystroke is *bound* to the macro, not *bonded*.

Comment: It is somewhat arbitrary that whoever coined such expressions chose 'bind' for their metaphor: they could easily have chosen 'bond', and then we would talk about "keys being bonded to macros", and it would make just as much sense. But in fact, "bond" is not used that way.