# "Bind" vs. "bond"

Tags: word-choice

*"In any relationship, the essence of trust is not in its bind, but in its bond."*

This idiom puzzles me because what is the difference between bind/bound and bond/bonded? When do I use bind, when do I use bond?

(Also, incidentally, who said this quote?)

- Related question: [“bound” or “bonded”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5175/bound-or-bonded)

Comment: There are [so many uses of this proverb](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22In+any+relationship,+the+essence+of+trust+is+not+in+its+bind,+but+in+its+bond.%22&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en&client=safari#q=%22In+any+relationship,+the+essence+of+trust+is+not+in+its+bind,+but+in+its+bond.%22) that to identify its original source is probably impossible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way I understand this idiom is that the two nouns *bind* and *bond* are contrasted, not the two verbs *bind* and *bond*.

A *bind* in this sense is the object that ties things together.  A *bond* is the result - that two things are tied together.  So this idiom is saying that we don't end up trusting each other because of *how* we are tied together, or *what* brought us together; rather that we trust each other because of the *bond* that formed between us - the closeness that we have for one another *because of* being somehow tied together.

Answer (score 0):

> "In any relationship, the essence of trust is not in its *bind*, but in its *bond*."

This is, frankly speaking, a rubbish aphorism thanks to its inscrutability. The two words are near synonyms.

The words *bind* and *bond* are being used here in the following senses.

[Bind](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bind):

> - **cause** (people) to feel united:
>
>   *the comradeship that had bound such a disparate bunch of lads together* <sup>1</sup>
> - **impose** a legal or contractual **obligation** on:
>
>   *a party who signs a document will normally be bound by its terms*

[Bond](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bond):

> a force or feeling that unites people; **a shared emotion or interest**:
>
> *there was a bond of understanding between them*

In other words, *bind* is being used to imply a *forced* connection thanks to external factors. *Bond* on the other hand indicates a *mutually shared* relationship. To attempt a little pithiness of my own, *a bind is made while a bond grows*.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>This example is probably a bit of a grey area. You can be *bound* together because you are comrades. Your *shared* experience as comrades can also create a *bond* between you.</sub>